# Hooks in React Native: Only Call Hooks from React Functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

There is [this section on React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) that I don't really understand what it is saying:

> **Only Call Hooks from React Functions**
>
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
>
> By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code.

What does it mean to only call Hooks from React function components and how is a React function different than what I would call a regular functional component?

In my mind they're the same:

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => //do stuff);

    return (
        // return some sort of stuff here
    )
}
```

The reason I ask is the eslint I have for hooks is complaining about the way I'm using `useState` here:

```
const checkPermissions = () => { //when I change this to 'usePermissions', it works fine
  const [locPermission, setLocPermission] = useState(null); // eslint error here
  //'React Hook "useState" is called in function "checkPermissions" which 
  //is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function.'


  //Check for and set state for permissions here

  return locPermission;
};
```

Comment: when you add `checkPermissions` to any "React function" (any function that returns a  React element) eslint might stop complaining. I agree this is confusing terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean is the entry point for a set of hooks should be within a React component and not elsewhere if it is used as a hook e.g. in this very arbitrary/simple example here:

**`my-utils/useCustomHook.js`** *arbitrary custom hook*

```js
import { setState } from 'React'

export default function useCustomHook() {
     const [state, setState] = useState(()=> 'anyRandomState');
     // ...possibly re-using other custom hooks here,
     // then returning something for our component to consume
}
```

**`MyComponent.js`** *Your React component*

```js
import React, { setState } from 'react'
import useCustomHook from 'my-utils/useCustomHook'

function MyComponent() {
     const offDaHook = useCustomHook();
     return (
          <div>
               Hi, I'm your component with a custom hook. 
               I see that the value returned was {offDaHook}. 
          </div>
     );
}
```

**`random-other-business-logic.js`** *another file which does other things that does not include rendering*

```js
import useCustomHook from `my-utils/useCustomHook.js`

useCustomHook(); // Arbitrarily calling from non React component!
// do other things...
```

One reason ESLint could/would complain is hooks should be formatted as `useXXX` e.g. in your case, rather than `checkPermissions`, something like `usePermissionChecker` (or `useCheckPermissions` depending on how you think in code) should get the linter to recognize that this function is a custom hook.

I also agree -- this phrasing could probably be improved -- the custom rules of hooks threw me for a little bit of a loop at first as well. I am not 100% sure why this is the case but this is just what I got from that.

I am not sure if React internally appends other variables to hooks such as counting their instances/prototypes but guessing that if the React team doesn't, they would like to reserve the right to do that going forward. In either case, it is a lot cleaner to separate your React-state code from your non-React business logic and hooks using the `useHooks` convention as they are a little bit funky with their nuances.

Definitely something interesting to look into and wish I could tell you more, but this is just from another user-world programmer currently.